# How to overwrite csv file of MySQL result set?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

My SQL query is given below,

```
select company.Company_name as COMPANY_NAME, 
IFNULL(followup.contact_date, ' ') AS FOLLOW_UP_DATE,
IFNULL((select Full_name from user where user_id = followup.user_id), ' ') AS Employee, 
IFNULL(fix_appoinment_order.appointment_dt, ' ') AS APPOINTMENT_DATE, 
IFNULL((select Full_name from user where user_id = fix_appoinment_order.user_tme), ' ') as TELEMARKETING_EXECUTIVE,
IFNULL((select Full_name from user where user_id = fix_appoinment_order.user_me), ' ') as MARKETING_EXECUTIVE
from company_order
inner join company on company.Company_id = company_order.Company_id
left join company_history on company_order.Compordr_id = company_history.compordr_id
left join followup on followup.followup_id = company_history.followup_id
left join fix_appoinment_order on fix_appoinment_order.fix_appointment_order_id = company_history.fix_appointment_order_id
where
followup.contact_date = date_format(now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, "%Y-%m-%d") OR 
fix_appoinment_order.appointment_dt = date_format(now() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, "%Y-%m-%d")
INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/backup/AppandFllups.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I know that, the query working fine, I have to set the cron job to get the result set as csv file and send email.

At first time when I execute the query, there is no issue, but next time I got the error as follows,

```
Error Code: 1086. File '/var/www/backup/AppandFllups.csv' already exists
```

I understood, the file is already created while I run at first time, but I am unable solve this issue. I used another cron job to fix this issue but it I am not satisfied, is there anyway to do achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL Documentation on `SELECT ... INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html)

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' form of SELECT writes the selected rows to a file. The file is created on the server host, so you must have the FILE privilege to use this syntax. file_name cannot be an existing file, which among other things prevents files such as /etc/passwd and database tables from being destroyed. The character_set_filesystem system variable controls the interpretation of the file name.

I suppose the easiest way would be the following:

## STEP #1

Change this line in the query

```
INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/backup/AppandFllups.csv'
```

to this

```
INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/backup/AppandFllups.tmp'
```

## STEP #2

Add these lines to the cronjob just after the dump

```
cd /var/www/backup
mv AppandFllups.tmp AppandFllups.csv
```

The main idea is to have `/var/www/backup/AppandFllups.tmp` be nonexistent just before the dump. The output file gets renamed to something you already use elsewhere. So, there is no need to change other processes or scripts.

## Give it a Try !!!